# Get Leaflet pop up to only show when feature properties are not null

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have GeoJSON data that contains URLs. Not all of the features have url data. I have a pop up which shows the name and a link to the url. I'd like to be able to only show the link to URL when the feature URL is not null but will always show the name as a minimum. My code  is below:

```
    const tackleshop_point = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "tackleshop",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 1,
        "name": "test 1",
        "url": "www.google.com"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.284362363619518, 50.983444094390933]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "gid": 7,
        "name": "test 2",
        "url": null
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.283893608524902, 50.981411456895998]
      }
    }
  ]
}

const tackleshop = L.geoJSON(tackleshop_point, {}).bindPopup(function(layer) {
  let cap_name = layer.feature.properties.name.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s+\w{1})/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());
  return `<p>${cap_name}</p><a href="http://${layer.feature.properties.url}" target="_blank">View<a>`
  /******/
  ;
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `bindPopup` method with a function, which finds out too late that the feature does not have a URL to show, in which case you actually want no popup, you can leverage the [`onEachFeature` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-oneachfeature) of the `L.geoJSON` factory to attach a popup conditionally:

> A `Function` that will be called once for each created `Feature`, after it has been created and styled. Useful for attaching events and popups to features.

```js
const tackleshop = L.geoJSON(tackleshop_point, {
  onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    const url = feature.properties.url;
    if (url) { // Attach the popup only when the url is specified
      layer.bindPopup(`<a href="http://${url}">View<a>`);
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: hi @ghybs - that works great, what I didn't explain sorry was that I need the pop up to also show the name. Each feature has a name but not all have a url.

Comment: Obviously the above is a simplified code to pinpoint the needed change to fix your issue, instead of burying it within tons of code. Feel free to adapt it to your exact need, with more complex template string to include more details.